# Shopify - targeting a list item

Tags: css, shopify

Hi I am trying to embolden the "clearance" tab on my website. It is being constructed with this Shopify code. Can I, in CSS, target this "clearance" element and embolden it?

[image]

```html
 <ul class="sf-menu">
        {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
        <!-- does this link in our iteration point to the current page? -->
        {% assign current = false %}{% if template == 'index' and link.url == '/' %}{% assign current = true %}{% elsif collection.url == link.url %}{% assign current = true %}{% elsif blog.url == link.url %}{% assign current = true %}{% elsif page.url == link.url %}{% assign current = true %}{% elsif page_title == link.title %}{% assign current = true %}{% elsif template == 'list-collections' and link.url == '/collections' %}{% assign current = true %}{% elsif page_title == 'Products' and link.url == '/collections/all' %}{% assign current = true %}{% elsif template == 'article' and link.url == article.url %}{% assign current = true %}{% endif %}
        <!-- end of soul-searching about active class -->
```

Comment: Maybe `.sf-menu>li:nth-child(2);` ?

Comment: Worked perfectly!. Thanks so much!!!